# Android: Samsung Galaxy S3 screen size for layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-screen

Is anyone out there testing on a Samsung Galaxy S3 yet?
   Specifically, does it have what is considered a large or normal screen for layout purposes?
   I have the Galaxy Nexus and it takes normal layouts, but I read the Galaxy Note is considered a large screen.
   Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a [link](http://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_i9300_galaxy_s_iii-4238.php) to the complete specifications for the European version of the Samsung Galaxy S3. The screen is 720 x 1280 pixels and 4.8 in. diagonal. The American version is the same as far as the screen goes.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am specifically interested in whether the phone interprets layouts from the res-layout or res-layout-large folder. 4.8in screens seem to be in the grey area between normal and large, which is why i'm concerned about screen real estate. thanks

Comment: @rus Unfortunately, this looks like something that we just have to wait until we can get our hands on one. That means that there's two ways you can go with this: you can choose to assume it's normal (because [well over 75 % of phones are](http://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=p&chs=400x250&chco=c4df9b,6fad0c&chl=Xlarge%20/%20mdpi|Large%20/%20ldpi|Large%20/%20mdpi|Normal%20/%20hdpi|Normal%20/%20ldpi|Normal%20/%20mdpi|Normal%20/%20xhdpi|Small%20/%20hdpi|Small%20/%20ldpi&chd=t%3A7.4,0.3,2.0,57.8,0.7,26.2,0.9,2.4,2.3)), or you can assume it's a small large, since it's barely on the cusp of normal.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I'll consider it normal, as I guess Samsung and Android would consider it a phone, not a tablet. We'll see.

Answer (score 36):

As owner of Samsung Galaxy S3 I confirm - it is "normal" screen, not "large" one. Also "xhdpi" when it comes to density.

Comment: I just tried Galaxy S4 and the `layout-normal` folder is used on this one as well.

Comment: @Voicu except the S4 density is "xxhdpi", as mentioned in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15475584/galaxy-s4-res-folder

Answer (score 13):

Samsung S3 takes images from drawable-sw360dp and layout files from layout-sw360dp folder only...

Answer (score 0):

all phones will use the drawable folder by default if no others are specified, but officially you should use xhdpi and hdpi for these

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm not worried about density, but rather screen size, specifically whether it would rather read layout xml files from either res-layout or res-layout-large. thanks.

Comment: Screen size often directly correlates with density, use hdpi for nexus and s3

Comment: Ah, ok, then use you be able to use res-layout for the galaxy s 3 typically layout-large would in my experience be something like the Dell streak or galaxy note

Answer (score 0):

Create a layout specifyc for Galaxy S3. [Android S3 layout vs Galaxy Nexus layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11699761/android-s3-layout-vs-galaxy-nexus-layout/12557007#12557007)