# Android S3 layout vs Galaxy Nexus layout

Tags: android, layout, screen-resolution, galaxy, galaxy-nexus

I've developed an app that was supposed to target both the Galaxy Nexus and the Galaxy S3. Both have 720 x 1280 screen resolutions and I have only used 'dp' values in my app. The resources exist in the 'layout-xhdpi' and the 'drawable-xhdpi' folders. Layout looks perfectly fine on the Nexus, but the padding values (in dp) is slightly off on the S3. I assume its because of the bigger screen size on S3 and difference in density.

How can I create a separate folder for Nexus and S3 so I can take into account the different screen sizes?

Answer (score 9):

Use this scheme:

For same layout landscape and portrait **layout-sw360dp**

Only for landscape **layout-sw360dp-land**

Only for portrait **layout-sw360dp-port**

I try to say you can use the before clasification creating folders with theses names. The layout located into are loaded in the Galaxy S3 - WXGA720. This is a way for disting the layout for this type of device. Its necesary Android 4.0+.

Comment: i have that folder still not being used

Answer (score 5):

I use `sw360dp-long` which the system will use for the GS3 and I use `sw360dp` for the Galaxy Nexus.

Comment: perfectly working. For galaxy s3 use `sw360dp-long` and for all other devices of similar category use `sw360dp.`

Answer (score 2):

Nexus 4: use sw384dp (768x1280)

Samsung S3: use sw360dp (720x1280)

It should be noted that both do fall into the sw360dp bucket, but some developers might need to make things pixel perfect, so the 384 folder might be needed but should be avoided if you can design a more flexible layout using LinearLayout and "weight" instead of hardcoding dp units.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the device model and can set layout.

As following you can get model

```
String phoneModel = android.os.Build.MODEL;
if(phoneModel.equals("ABC")) {
    // SET Ralated Layout
} else if(phoneModel.equals("XYZ")) {
    // SET Ralated Layout
}
```

Comment: surely there's a better way to do this. I need to change the xml not the java code.