# scroll activity page when key board is open android

Tags: java, android, layout, scroll

I want that whent the soft key board is open the activity page will scrolled.

To do this I added scroll View in xml,

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    tools:context="com.example.trying.MainActivity" 
    >


    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
         >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/LayoutBackground"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
             android:background="@drawable/background" 
           >

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/hello_world" >

              <requestFocus />
           </EditText>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

and changed the realativeLayout height in code:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

         Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
         Point size = new Point();
         display.getSize(size);
         int height = size.y;

         int x=getActionBarHeight();//in this line I get the actionBar height programicaly the function is in the end of page


         RelativeLayout l= (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.LayoutBackground);
         l.getLayoutParams().height = (height-x);//the layout size = size of full screen - size of actionBar




    }

    //I saw this function in stackOverflow site. function to get the actionBar height
    public int getActionBarHeight() {

            TypedValue tv = new TypedValue();
            getApplicationContext().getTheme().resolveAttribute(android.R.attr.actionBarSize, tv, true);
            int actionBarHeight = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(tv.resourceId);
            return actionBarHeight;
        }
```

manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.trying"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="16"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" 
             android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

The idia is that the layout heigt is depended of screen size (all devices), and action bar heigt too.

My problem is that when I run the app, the background is small.
the it's It seems that the action bar size fell twice,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following line of code to your manifest for the particular activity

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

Comment: @RohitArya it's not duplicate...same problem was also in my project, i also use your like solution but did not get success. but after only using adjustResize my problem was resolved.

Comment: @RohitArya I can show you...<activity
            android:name=".activity.CreateAddSubjectActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_create_add_subject"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        </activity>

Comment: @RohitArya..Dear there is a lots of difference in between your and mine answer...you should know.

Comment: @Toda You just use adjustResize in the place of stateHidden.

Comment: I added your line in manifest but nothing, I already have the space between the finish of page and layout edge.

Comment: @TodaWill you please add the following line in your xml file for Scrollview android:fillViewport="true"and tell me what happens

Comment: The problem is not to scroll the page, is that the layout isn't have the same heigt like the screen size, so I have some space between the layout buttom and screen buttom, the space is look like the same height like the action bar height...

Comment: thank you! its work well on galaxy s4 but on galaxy s3 the background is stretched, do you have any idia?

Comment: @Toda. actually for stretching problem you have to control the height and width factor of the layout

Comment: Why in one resolution its work weel, and in another not?

Comment: We have to maintain different different sizes for different different screen resolutions see following link http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: If I get action bar size and screen size programicaly, is it not solve the problem?

Comment: But you have to accordingly maintain the layout size too

Comment: depnds..how you did? basically its not your concern. if you have any confusion then change the code accordingly

Comment: I put mark to your answer but its still not work for me on galaxy s3... can you give me link for example?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20488512/android-how-to-differentiate-galaxy-s-3-and-galaxy-s-4-layouts

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11036158/android-samsung-galaxy-s3-screen-size-for-layout

Comment: Thank you lot, Does that mean I have to put different sizes of background? is it make the stretching problem?

Comment: I puted green vi to your answer, what I need to to do more? I don't understand I'm new in this site...

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add ScrollView in your layout. Remove it from xml. Then in AndroidManifest.xml, add the following lines in your activity:

```
<activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
          android:configChanges="keyboardHidden"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|stateAlwaysHidden" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: Please keep in mind that, the page will only be scrolled up to focus the edittext, when the field is going to be behind the keyboard. If the field is placed above the keyboard size area, the view will never scroll up.

Comment: Try to place the field at bottom and then check whether is it working or not.