# Galaxy s4 res folder

Tags: android, android-4.2-jelly-bean, galaxy

Galaxy s4

Screen: 4.99", 1920x1080 (FullHD).

Which the res folder would be used in FHD and what's the dpi value should be set?

xhdpi or xxhdpi? And how can I calculate it?

I didn't find any info in the developer docs and in the [screens_support](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) article

Comment: Nobody will know for certain until the device ships. Please wait until the device ships.

Answer (score 3):

It's 441 dpi, isn't it? So almost certainly xxhdpi, which is already supported in the Android framework. But why worry about it at this time? Assuming you're already supporting xhdpi, the likelihood that the average user can detect the different between xhdpi and xxhdpi assets is becoming increasingly small.

-- Edit --

Actually, I'd say it's certain to be xxhdpi, given that this is already in use with the new HTC One (which is at 468dpi).