# Which layout and density is fo Samsung Galaxy S3?

Tags: android, eclipse

Question is very short. How do I name folder for layout (example: layout-xhdpi) and how do I name folder for images (example: drawable-xhdpi)?

S3: http://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_i9300_galaxy_s_iii-4238.php

I've tryed to set folder names like I mentioned upper but results is not ok.

I'm trying this almost for couple of hours so I'm hoppe there is somebody who knows how to solve that.

Comment: This app will tell you: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jotabout.screeninfo&hl=en

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`layout-xhdpi` is a code smell. Bitmap drawable resources, and *maybe* dimension resources, should have density-specific versions. Layouts should not.

[The screen size is `-normal` and the density is `-xhdpi`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11651339/115145).

> I've tryed to set folder names like I mentioned upper but results is not ok.

Feel free to ask a separate StackOverflow question where you explain **completely and precisely** what "not ok" means.

Comment: I have create layout-xhdpi/main.xml and drawable-xhdpi and result is distoreted app

Comment: @CroiOS: There are many Android developer support sites on the Internet, offering help in many languages. I have some of these sites listed at http://www.andglobe.com. You may have better luck using a site in a language that is more comfortable for you.

Comment: So you want to say if my english is not great like yours I should not ask any questions here?

Comment: @CroiOS: Everyone is better off asking questions in their native language, if that option exists. That is why I am trying to promote these other sites, so that more developers can get more help in their native language.